# How to count the number of variable in a column in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

dataframe `test_df` containing series `a b c d e` 
I need to count the number of each unique variable in a that has abc in e
then divide that number by the sum of `b` and `c` and output new dataframe
containing a d and g=sum of b and c

`

```
test_df
a b c d e 
1 3 4 5 abc00 
2 6 5 3 12abc
1 3 1 4 5    >>>>this row will be left out 
1 4 7 3 sdabc
1 4 5 6 78abc
2 2 4 5 abc
3 2 3 4 kk abc
3 4 6 7 abc
2 6 7 9 abcd
1 7 4 1 abcabc
```

output will be

output_df
    a d g
    1 5 7
    2 3 11
    1 3 11
    1 6 9
    2 5 6
    3 4 5
    3 7 10
    2 9 13
    1 1 11

`

[image: image for input data here]

[image: image for output data here]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['g'] = df['b']+df['c']
df.drop(['b','c', 'e'], axis=1,inplace = True)
```

Comment: thanks mate, i am still unable to figure out how to count the occurrence of a for every corresponding e that has string abc in it

Comment: I do not understand the question. If the code gives the out put you expected, you can accept the answer. You can ask a new question for the new requirement.